# Python Optional Argument Pair

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using the `argparse` module to get two optional command line arguments:

```
parser.add_argument('start_date', nargs='?', metavar='START DATE',
                   help='start date in YYYY-MM-DD')
parser.add_argument('end_date', nargs='?', metavar='END DATE',
                   help='end date in YYYY-MM-DD')
```

which gives

```
> python test_arg.py -h
usage: test_arg.py [-h] [START DATE] [END DATE]
```

However I want the pair of optional arguments (`START DATE` and `END DATE`), if provided at all, to be provided together. Something like along this line:

```
usage: test_arg.py [-h] [START_DATE END_DATE]
```

Is it possible with `argparse`?

Comment: Hey, on a tangent, I really advocate for `docopt` as cooler than `argparse`. Try it out sometime!

Comment: @Murph: Does docopt support this use case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The closest I can come up with is:

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--dates', nargs=2, metavar=('START DATE','END_DATE'),
                   help='start date and end date in YYYY-MM-DD')
print(parser.format_help())
```

which produces

```
usage: stock19805170.py [-h] [--dates START DATE END_DATE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --dates START DATE END_DATE
                        start date and end date in YYYY-MM-DD
```

There isn't a way of specifying - `'require these 2  arguments together'`.  `nargs=2` specifies 2 arguments, but doesn't make them optional (a `nargs=[0,2]` form has been proposed but not incorporated into any distribution).  So `--dates` is needed to make it optional.  To produce this help, the metavar must be a tuple (try it with a list to see what I mean).  And that `tuple metavar` only works for `optionals` (not positionals).

Comment: This is the best way to do it as far as I know. It's what `nargs` is there for. Also worth noting: IMO, it's usually easier to just write the usage message yourself (pass it to the `ArgumentParser` constructor) than to coerce the default usage message to look just how you want it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to do this is to do the check yourself:

```
if (not parser.start_date) != (not parser.end_date):
    print("Error: --start_date and --end_date must be used together.")
    arg_parser.print_usage()
    sys.exit(-1)
```

Unfortunately, that's not reflected in the help message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add default=None as variable

```
parser.add_argument('start_date', nargs='?', metavar='START DATE',
                   help='start date in YYYY-MM-DD', default=None)
parser.add_argument('end_date', nargs='?', metavar='END DATE',
                   help='end date in YYYY-MM-DD', default=None)
```

I think that should work.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?