# Paired optional arguments

Tags: python

I have a function with two optional arguments that I'd like to require either both, or neither to be specified. What is the preferred way of enforcing this in Python? My current approach seems a bit awkward:

```
def myfunc(data, opt1=None, opt2=None):
    if opt1 is None or opt2 is None:
        if not (opt1 is None and opt2 is None):
            raise ValueError("Must specify both opt1 and opt2 or neither.")
```

This question: [Python Optional Argument Pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19805170/python-optional-argument-pair) is the same as mine, but in the context of `argparse` specifically; I am interested in the default way of doing this within functions generally.

Comment: `if (opt1 is None)!=(opt2 is None): raise ValueError(...)`

Comment: I think your approach is about the best you can do. There is no real "trick" in Python for enforcing both or neither optional parameters besides just checking it with an if statement in the function.

Answer (score 3):

The simplified condition you're looking for is:

```
if (opt1 is None) != (opt2 is None):
    raise ...
```

This condition is true if both arguments don't fall on the same side of `is None` together.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function

```
def ensure_both_or_neither(opt1, opt2):
    if opt1 is None or opt2 is None:
        if not (opt1 is None and opt2 is None):
            raise ValueError("Must specify both opt1 and opt2 or neither.")
```

Then call it from your function:

```
def myfunc(data, opt1=None, opt2=None):
    ensure_both_or_neither(opt1, opt2)
```

I don't think it's any better than your orignal approach, but it is slightly more explicit / readable?

Answer (score 1):

```
def myfunc(data, *args):
    if(len(args)==0 or len(args)==2):
        #do something
```

Is how I would do it

This also enables you to have as many arguments as you want, and only if none or 2 are used the code is run

Comment: Fair enough, but I'd like there to possibly be more optional arguments besides this, and the counting could get complicated. However, I didn't specify that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that a `set` removes duplicates:

```
def myfunc(data, opt1=None, opt2=None):
    if len({opt1 is None, opt2 is None}) - 1:
        raise ValueError("Must specify both opt1 and opt2 or neither.")
```

You could do it for any number of parameters:

```
def myfunc(data, *args):
    if len({arg is None for arg in args}) - 1:
        raise ValueError("Must specify all parameters or none.")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need neither or both, don't accept two separate arguments; accept a single optional tuple and *document* it. Don't give the user the opportunity to only provide one.

```
def myfunc(data, opts=None):
    """blah blah blah

    opts, if given, should be a tuple with two values, neither None.
    """
    opt1, opt2 = opts if opts is not None else (None, None)
```

You could make the default `(None, None)`, which would simplify the unpacking inside your function (`x1, x2 = opts`), but at the expense of cluttering your function's signature.

(In reality, `opts` can be an iterable with 2 elements, but if the user makes a call like `myfunc(data, "hi")` and expects `opt1` to be `hi` and `opt2` to be `None`, that's his fault, not yours.)

Comment: What if the tuple is `(3, None)`?  There is still the same problem.

Comment: I'd call that user error; they didn't forget to supply a second argument, they explicitly *chose* to provide a value of `None` against the documented requirements. (Ultimately, this boils down to type-checking, which at runtime is generally the responsibility of the caller in Python.)

Comment: I thought about this, but it seems like in the (3, None) case we might have code that produces silently incorrect behaviour. We could of course guard against this using explicit checks within the function but then we are in the same situation as before. So it's not clear to me how the tuple actually helps. Put differently, we could just as well rely on external documentation *without* the tuple.

Comment: I'd say its main purpose is to more clearly document your intent. Having two separate arguments with default values strongly implies that you can omit either one independently. Having one argument removes that possibility; you can only specify an incorrect value like `(3, None)` *explicitly*, rather than letting a default value be used.

Comment: You can also be more explicit defining what the tuple should be: two `int`s, six lists, a `str` and a `dict`, etc.